# Accesing timer register in mode 2 on microcontroller 8051

Tags: c, timer, microcontroller

Could someone please help me out with this example. I dont understand why the they did not use (25μs × 1000). Why did they break it down to (25μs × 250 × 40) and later load (25μs × 250 × 36) on the microcontroller instead. Thank you.

Example 14: Write an 8051 C program to toggle only pin P1.5 continuously every 250 ms.
Use Timer 0, mode 2 (8-bit auto-reload) to create the delay.

Solution:
Solution: Assume XTAL=11.0592MHz
For the delay of 250ms the count exceeds 256. hence, count for 25μs is calculated and count is 23

Therefore for 250ms =>25μs × 250 × 40 = 250 ms

Program

```
#include <reg51.h>
void T0M2Delay(void);
sbit mybit=P1^5;
sbit mybit=P1^5;

void T0M2Delay(void);
sbit mybit=P1^5;
void main(void){
    unsigned char x,y;
    while (1) {
        mybit=~mybit;
        for (x=0;x<250;x++)
        for (y=0;y<36;y++) //we put 36, not 40
        T0M2Delay();
     }
}
void T0M2Delay(void){
    TMOD=0x02;
    TH0=-23;
    TR0=1;
    while (TF0==0);
    TR0=0;
    TF0=0;
}
```

Comment: Because it's only an 8 bit register, so it can only work with a range of 0..255, hence the choice of 250 as a conveniently large value < 255.

Comment: thank you Paul R, so why didnt this loop                                                  for (x=0;x<250;x++)
        for (y=0;y<36;y++)   just be for(x=0; x<1000; x++) why was  250 and 36 used instead.

Comment: @Paul , Is it possible to use 250ms =>50μs × 250 × 20, how would i go about with the loops then.

Comment: Sorry - my bad - I didn't look closely enough - the same logic applies though: `x` and `y` are both `unsigned char` so only have a range of 0..255. This is more efficient on a low end 8 bit micro-controller like the 8051, where registers are 8 bits. You can use an `int` and larger values if you like, but it will be a little less efficient.

Comment: Thank you @Paul, its now clear.